# DialogFragment - Setting status bar color not working on some devices

Tags: android, statusbar, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to change the status bar color in a DialogFragment.

However, on some devices, like OnePlus6 (Android 9) it doesn't work.

Furthermore it makes the status bar icons dissapear.

Here's the snippet I'm using:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
window.statusBarColor = Color.WHITE
```

Also tried:

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.FLAG_FULL_SCREEN);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23782242)

Comment: @ths can you explain your comment little more please. I have asked to check this statement in his code.

Comment: that should be a comment not an answer.